# Javascript array filter child！

Tags: javascript, node.js

The first array is as follows：

```js
   var arr = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: 'aa',
    children: [
      {
        key: 2,
        title: 'bb',
        children: [
          {
            key: 3,
            title: 'cc', 
            children: [
              {
                key: 5,
                title: 'ee', 
                children: [
                  {
                    key: 6,
                    title: 'ff'
                  },
                  {
                    key: 7,
                    title: 'gg'
                  },
                  {
                    key: 8,
                    title: 'hh'
                  }                  
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            key: 4,
            title: 'dd', 
          }          
        ]
      }    
    ]
  }
]
console.log(arr)
```

If the second array is as follows：

```
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
```

Then I expect array 3 to be as follows：

```
arr3 = [4, 8]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Ok, so your first two examples make sense but then you start talking about `If is the second array, then I expect the final array to be as follows` which completely lost me. Could you expand on this point and how you expect to obtain `arr3`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder love the *you get a badge!* good way to insight people to do the tour. +1

Comment: @kemicofa - :-) It does mean I have to do a few clicks each time to make sure they don't already have it, but I think it's worth it.

Comment: Please elaborate more. We don't understand what do you want.

Comment: Please describe that logic in words, so we do not have to figure out what you mean by comparing the results with the input. I assume you're trying to filter out a certain subset of children of the array based on a string input, but the exact rules elude me.

Comment: I understand you want to make a recursive function to get all childs keys but just like @kemicofa, you lost me with `If is the second array, then I expect the final array to be as follows`

Comment: @kemicofa If arr1's parent or child returns arr1's key combination array in arr2

Comment: @Kévin Huang arr2 is variable

Comment: @mxh861001 Then, can you explain why if my `arr2` is equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 8]`, then `arr3` will be equal to `[4, 8]` ?

Comment: @Kévin Huang  I want to use arr2 to get the child of arr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the pathes first and then filter the given key, if it is more than in two pathes, then filter out this value.

```js
function filter(source, targets) {

    function getPath(array, target) {
        return array.reduce((r, { key, children }) => {
            var temp;
            if (key === target) return r.concat(key);
            if (children) {
                temp = getPath(children, target);
                if (temp.length) return r.concat(key, temp);
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
    }

    var temp = targets.map(k => getPath(source, k));
    return targets.filter(v => !temp.some((c => a => a.includes(v) && ++c)(-1)));
}

var array = [{ key: 1, title: 'aa', children: [{ key: 2, title: 'bb', children: [{ key: 3, title: 'cc', children: [{ key: 5, title: 'ee', children: [{ key: 6, title: 'ff' }, { key: 7, title: 'gg' }, { key: 8, title: 'hh' }] }] }, { key: 4, title: 'dd', }] }] }],
    result = filter(array, [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]);

console.log(result);
```